# Full Outer Join returning too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

What I'm trying to achieve is a data set where by I have a set of holdings data against its benchmark and show where the holdings are either on or off benchmark.  The data set should look like this:

```
PositionDate   PortfolioCode   Benchmark   SecurityDesciption   PortfolioWeight   BenchmarkWeight
2017-03-31     Port1           JPM         Sec1                 1.00              1.5
2017-03-31     Port1           JPM         Sec2                 0.54              NULL
2017-03-31     Port1           JPM         Sec3                 NULL              0.5
```

My SQL currently looks like the following with a FULL OUTER JOIN so that you can return weights from both the portfolio data and the benchmark data depending on whether the portfolio holds it or not:

```
SELECT 
        lt.PositionDate                                                         AS PositionDate
    ,   lt.PortfolioCode                                                        AS PortfolioCode
    ,   gpi.indx_desc                                                           AS Benchmark
    ,   i.iss_desc                                                              AS SecurityDescription
    ,   lt.BaseCCYEffectiveExposure / NULLIF(lt.TOTALPortfolioMV_BaseCcy,0)     AS PortfolioWeight          
    ,   issindx.WGHT_EOD                                                        AS BenchmarkWeight

FROM #Lkthru AS lt

    INNER JOIN ISSUE_DG AS i
        ON i.INSTR_ID = lt.ID_NETIK_INSTR_ID

    INNER JOIN GP_BNCHMRK_XREF AS bxref     -- Portfolio Benchmark Crossreference
        ON bxref.acct_id = lt.portfoliocode -- Links to Portfolio
        AND bxref.bnchmrk_type = 'Primary'  -- Link to reporting benchmark
        AND (@EndDate BETWEEN bxref.start_tms AND ISNULL(bxref.end_tms,@EndDate))  -- Ensures you pick up the correct benchmark for the date you are reporting for

    INNER JOIN gp_index AS gpi
        ON gpi.indx_id = bxref.indx_id      -- Links to GP_INDEX to pick up the correct benchmark

    FULL OUTER JOIN iss_indx_cnstnt AS issindx      -- Join to ensure we have all constituents of benchmark returned as well as all portfolio constituents
        ON issindx.indx_instr_id = gpi.INSTR_ID
        AND issindx.cnstnt_instr_id = i.instr_id    -- Join to constituents of portfolio
        AND issindx.as_of_dte = @EndDate
```

However I'm not returning the desired result set and I seem to be getting every record from ISS_INDX_CNSNT returned.  It must be something to do with the filters after the ON on my FULL OUTER JOIN or its just not possible to do what I'm trying to achieve?  I'm trying to avoid having to put the filtered data into a temp table and then join or creating a UNION ALL and then GROUP BY.

Does anyone have an ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT - included working example**

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @EndDate = '2017-03-31'

DECLARE @Port TABLE
(
    PortCode    VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO @Port VALUES ('Port1')

DECLARE @Lkthru TABLE
(
    PositionDate    DATETIME    
,   PortfolioCode   VARCHAR(40)
,   Instr_ID        VARCHAR(40)
,   PortfolioWeight FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Lkthru VALUES('2017-03-31','Port1','1',1.00)
INSERT INTO @Lkthru VALUES('2017-03-31','Port1','2',0.54)

DECLARE @Issue_DG TABLE
(
    Instr_ID        VARCHAR(40)
,   SecurityDesc    VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Issue_DG VALUES ('1','Sec1')
INSERT INTO @Issue_DG VALUES ('2','Sec2')
INSERT INTO @Issue_DG VALUES ('3','Sec3')
INSERT INTO @Issue_DG VALUES ('4','Sec4')

DECLARE @GP_BNCHRK_XREF TABLE
(
    PortfolioCode   VARCHAR(40)
,   BenchmarkID     VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO @GP_BNCHRK_XREF VALUES ('Port1','JPM1')

DECLARE @GPIndex TABLE
(
    BenchmarkID     VARCHAR(40)
,   BenchmarkNme    VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO @GPIndex VALUES ('JPM1','JPM')

DECLARE @IssueIndexConst TABLE
(
    BenchmarkDate   DATETIME
,   BenchmarkID     VARCHAR(40)
,   Const_ID        VARCHAR(40)
,   BenchmarkWeight FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @IssueIndexConst VALUES ('2017-03-31','JPM1','1',1.5)
INSERT INTO @IssueIndexConst VALUES ('2017-03-31','JPM1','3',0.5)
INSERT INTO @IssueIndexConst VALUES ('2017-03-31','JPM1','4',0.5)
INSERT INTO @IssueIndexConst VALUES ('2017-02-28','JPM1','1',1.5)
INSERT INTO @IssueIndexConst VALUES ('2017-02-28','JPM1','3',0.5)
INSERT INTO @IssueIndexConst VALUES ('2017-02-28','JPM1','4',0.5)

SELECT 
        ISNULL(lt.PositionDate,issindx.BenchmarkDate)   AS PositionDate
    ,   ISNULL(lt.PortfolioCode,bxref2.PortfolioCode)   AS PortfolioCode
    ,   ISNULL(gpi.BenchmarkNme,gpi2.BenchmarkNme)      AS Benchmark
    ,   ISNULL(i.SecurityDesc,ib.SecurityDesc)          AS SecurityDesc
    ,   lt.PortfolioWeight
    ,   issindx.BenchmarkWeight

FROM @GP_BNCHRK_XREF AS bxref

    INNER JOIN @Lkthru AS lt
        ON lt.PortfolioCode = bxref.PortfolioCode

    INNER JOIN @Issue_DG AS i
        ON i.Instr_ID = lt.Instr_ID

    INNER JOIN @GPIndex AS gpi
        ON gpi.BenchmarkID = bxref.BenchmarkID

    FULL OUTER JOIN @IssueIndexConst AS issindx
        ON issindx.BenchmarkID = gpi.BenchmarkID
        AND issindx.Const_ID = i.Instr_ID
        AND issindx.BenchmarkDate = @EndDate

    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Issue_DG AS ib
        ON ib.Instr_ID = issindx.Const_ID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN @GPIndex AS gpi2
        ON gpi2.BenchmarkID = issindx.BenchmarkID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN @GP_BNCHRK_XREF AS bxref2
        ON bxref2.BenchmarkID = issindx.BenchmarkID
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You are saying that you get records issindx for `as_of_dte <> @EndDate` too? You may want to put `issindx.as_of_dte` in your select list to check this.

Comment: Point taken, working example attached with sample data.  As you'll see I seem to be retrieving all records from @IssueIndexConst table in my example.  I just want the date passed to be returned from that join.  I thought the filter I've added to that join would be sufficient?

Comment: Why does it have to be a FULL join to issindx ? Why not a LEFT join?

Comment: Use subquery from `@IssueIndexConst` with `where` condition on `benchmarkdate`. `on` condition filters out joined records only.

Comment: Needs to be full outer so that I return data from both @ Lkthru where it matches from @ IssueIndexConst and also where it doesn't match.

So the benchmark date will only be applied to joined records?  Is there no way of adding another filter to ensure I only get the benchmark IDs and dates I require without going down the sub query route or adding all the data into a temp table and join the temp table to my full query?